# Setting maxFeatures on vector openlayer layer

Tags: openlayers-3

So I use Openlayers 3.9.0 and I use a `loader` to get a vector layer from Geoserver. Here is the code that currently works.

```
    var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function (extent) {
            $.ajax('http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfsservice=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:mylayer&outputFormat=application/json', 
            {type: 'GET'})
            .done(      
             function(response) {
                        var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});
                        sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,{dataProjection :projection,featureProjection : projection}));
                    })
            .fail(function () {alert("BAD");});
        },
        strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}))
    });
```

By setting a `maxFeatures` (`...&maxFeatures=50&...`) to my url I dont get all the features. Does this means that if I zoom in I will see more features and if I zoom out I will see less? Is `maxFeatures` related to the `bbox` and renders features according to the current map view and zoom levels? Or this isnt the concept? Because in my case , I always see a fixed number of features.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loader function of an `ol.source.Vector` is called with an extent, a resolution and a projection. The semantic expectation is that the loader function is responsible for loading all features within that extent.

`ol.source.Vector` maintains a history of all loaded extents, and will not try to load an extent that is within the already loaded extents.

So if you use the `tile` loading strategy at a low zoom level, and your `maxFeatures` causes some features to be ignored, zooming in will not make them appear (because loading that extent should already have been done be the parent tile load).

Because of this, **using the WFS parameter `maxFeatures` with `ol.source.Vector` is generally a bad idea**. If you really need to limit the number of features per request, consider limiting your layer to higher zoom levels or making several request for each loader call.

Additionally, your loader code does not use the `extent` parameter, making each request identical. Your loaders only responsibility is to load the features within the given extent. If you want to load all features independently of their location, use the `all` loading strategy.

Comment: So, "get rid of maxFeatures" is a general rule? Or it can be usefull combined with other settings? For example `maxFeatures` and strategy bbox ? I think this combination will load only 50 features per zoom level and if I zoom in, it will reload another new 50, according to zoom and current view. Or not? Also, about my loader code, I use the `extend` parameter here `loader: function (extent)...` Where else should I use it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, skip it unless you really need to. And if you really need to, you should probably find a better way.

Comment: You should use the extent to generate a BBOX parameter in the WFS url

Comment: A better way, compared to what? The maxFeatures-bbox strategy combination?

Comment: @slevin compared to loading the features in multiple requests or accepting lost features when using maxFeatures.